# Windows 10 won't boot, won't enter safe mode, stuck in recovery environment

Tags: windows-10, boot

I left my computer for a bit and come back to find it in the recovery environment.

I tried the automatic repair options, startup repair, no change.
I used the console to do sfc check, it did fix some files, but still no booting.

In the recovery environment, I tried to enter safe mode using the start up settings, I get the menu, but it did not boot.

I tried to enable boot logging, but the ntblog.txt has not changed.

I don't have a restore point.

BCD looks good, but I did a rebuild, just in case.

Hardware all looks good. I swapped the graphics card, disabled all usb devices, just to be sure, nothing helped.
I can access all drives and files from the console in the recovery environment.

I would like to get a sense of where it is failing, preferably boot into safe mode, or failing any options, try an inplace upgrade, but AFAIK, it has to be started from the OS.

Any ideas what to try next?

OS: Windows 10
CPU: i7 3970x
MB: Gigabyte x79 ud5

Comment: I wouldn't know, but I really wonder why the person who downvoted the question did so. Looks like a good one to me.

Comment: So every time you boot it enters safe mode?

Comment: stendarr, there, made the title more understandable.

Comment: @FrankConijn, the issue is that troubleshooting questions are very hard to handle in a Q&A format unless enough diagnostic information is included so that there is a definitive answer, or the problem is recognizable from its signature.  The close vote (and probably the downvote) is for being too broad.  Requesting diagnostic suggestions isn't a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen a lot with certain updates are applied.

The only way you could restore is with a repair ran from the original disk you installed windows with.

Boot from the disk and use the repair options.