# Windows 10 died suddenly, can't access hard drive

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, liveusb

I'm having a kinda bizarre problem right now. First of all, just to be specific, the problem is with a MSI GV62 laptop that came with Windows 10 preinstalled. To be completely honest, I didn't mess with the OS too much since I got the laptop (which was about a month ago). Only issue I had was when I tried to edit registry items because I was having (minor) issues with the trackpad and none of the conventional methods were working, but other than that everything else remained untouched. I'm sorry that maybe this is too vague, but I don't know the origin of the problem so this is all the background I know as of right now. Now, this is my problem:

Windows 10 basically just died on me, and I have no idea why. I wish I could give more information about what happened, but the way it happened was that I was using my laptop normally, went to take a shower and when I came back the laptop had shut down. When I tried to turn it on it would just boot into Advanced Startup Options, and nothing I tried would work. It wouldn't boot into safe mode, it wouldn't reset (while trying to keep my files), and basically everything else didn't work, including rebuilding BCD. Also tried using the MSI recovery tool which would basically reset my laptop back to factory settings, but it got stuck for like over an hour on a screen that just said something like 'Operating System: Windows 10', so I forcefully shut it down, because I thought it was just frozen. It was probably a bad mistake because after that BSOD would show directly after trying to boot up Windows.

I somehow managed to get back to the Advanced Startup Options screen again. But now I'm cornered into reinstalling Windows 10, and there a few files I would really like to back up, even though I have a backup of most of my hard drive. I tried booting into Ubuntu from an USB flash drive and managed to run it successfully, but for some reason it refuses to show my HDD. It's not even that it is unmounted, it simply won't show up after looking for all the storage devices on the terminal.

The question I found was closest to the problem was [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1320280/windows-10-wont-boot-wont-enter-safe-mode-stuck-in-recovery-environment), but the only answer suggests to reinstall Windows, and I'd want to exhaust all other options to at least access my hard drive before resorting to a hard reset.

So now, here are the questions:

1. Is there any option left to salvage the few remaining files? I have access to Ubuntu in that computer, as I said earlier, but so far it can't find my disk
2. What could have possibly caused this issue in the first place? I know that my information isn't enough to accurately assess the issue, but I find it hard to believe that editing a registry regarding a touchpad gesture was enough to kill Windows 10 within a month, and I didn't (personally) modify or download anything else, so unless it was an error from a Windows update then I can't see what could have caused this
3. Just in case, is there anything else I should attempt before completely resetting the laptop back to factory settings? That's my last option, so I want to try everything else that's possible

Again, I'm sorry that I can't give any more useful information. I know that these kinds of specific troubleshooting questions can be objectionable to say the least, but as of right now this is my last resort, and I'm personally also a bit baffled.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows has become unbootable, boot with a Linux live CD or USB and copy your files.

However, if Linux doesn't see your disk, then you are in trouble.
In that case, perhaps a repair-shop can still save your files.

I suggest that after saving the files, ask for the computer to be replaced by warranty,
rather than trying to fix such a bad lemon.
It's not normal for a hard disk to go bad after only one month.